# повтор функции проверки пользователей

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема. По коду должна проводиться проверка пользователя на принадлежность его к определённой группе. Она отрабатывает корректно, но повторном перевыборе "Председателя"/"Председательствующий" , проверка не происходит. Т.е. мне необходимо запретить всем группа, кроме определённых(заданы в отдельном запросе) - выбирать "кофе-брейк" и "питьевая вода". Если выбираю в самом начале пользователя - то скрипт отрабатывает, но если я перевыберу пользователя - то проверка пользователя на принадлежность к группе не происходит повторно, а остаётся старая группа. К сожалению не являюсь разработчиком и даже джуниором, потому имею проблему с понимаем этого бага. Исходный код прилагаю.

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KocM/jRnCCMU72

Пытался доработать повтор ajax запроса, но к сожалению скрип повторно не отрабатывал. По сути есть два решения:

1. При каждом выборе (или при критичном переключении, например был выбран "участник", а выбор переключается на "организатора", у которого доступа больше) перезагружать страницу. 
   === Довольно простой вариант, с точки зрения разработки, но много перезагрузок страницы (сбивается внимание пользователя, ему нужно дольше ждать);
2. При каждом выборе запускается аякс-запрос, который перепроверяет доступы и перерисовывает изменившиеся части страницы. Например, было доступна только опция кофе-брейк, а добавилось ещё "встреча со звездой" или "селфи с лектором".
   === Сложнее в реализации, но... так по-идее всё и должно работать.

К сожалению ни первый, ни второй вариант реализовать мне не удалось

Answer (score 0):

Так как все в template.php и отрабатывается код один раз, а потом нет, у вас скорее всего кэшируется вся информация. Для теста, выключите кэш и посмотрите будет ли работать. Если да, то нужно доп логику вынести за пределы кэшируемой области, ну или выключишь кэш у конкретного компонента (тут уже все зависит от напряженности проекта и данной страницы в целом)

Comment: Боюсь не в кэше проблема. Попробовал сделать запрет кэш на странице, к сожалению это эффекта не дало. Хотя не исключаю возможность, что сделал неверно и кэш продолжил заполняться.

Comment: глобально в настройках на время отключи кэш и попробуй проверить, либо если это тестовая среда, можешь почистить папку `/bitrix/cache/` для уверенности и проверить )

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка было не в кэш, была в неверном возврате значений после определения департамента. Преобразовал возврат из 3 в 1, начало отрабатывать. После скорректировал отображение чекбоксов при проверке.